# Random forest at cutoff 1

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am playing with different decision cutoffs for my RF model. When I select a cutoff of 1.0, I expect my model to be highly precise in detecting the positive  samples but with a low recall. However scikit shows a precision and recall of 0 at cutoff 1.0? Why is it like that?

Comment: add some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicted probabilities of being in the positive class will be in the interval `(0,1)`. I am putting an open interval because, numerically, no probability will be exactly one, but rather a very close number. If you set a cutoff at exactly one, all your predicted probabilities will be below the cutoff, and everything will be classified as negative as @parsa said!

Since both precision and recall have at the numerator the number of TRUE POSITIVES, they will both be 0, because your model will have predicted everything as negative and you will have 0 true or false positives

Comment: Thank you. I see your explanation and it makes sense. I am just now thinking that in my application, what I want to achieve is that "a sample should only be classified as positive" if all trees in a random forest predict it to be positive. So instead of majority voting as by default, I expect a consensus of all trees to classify a sample. That is why I was thinking about cutoff of 1. How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

it predicts anything to be 0
so there is no true positive at all if it considered 1 class
so it's reasonable to show 0 for both